# ContentType of UITextField is not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, ios14

```
    textField_firstName.autocorrectionType = .yes
    textField_firstName.textContentType = .givenName
    textField_firstName.keyboardType = .namePhonePad
```

Here is my code for autofill First Name in UITextField on my SignUp form. But it is not working properly. Its repeating first name on some devices means first name appear twice when tap on suggestion and on some devices its not working at all. Any help will be highly appreciable.

Regards,

Comment: My autofill code also not working on properly on "Last Name", "Phone" & "Email" field.

Comment: Did you test on a real device ?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini yes, I am testing on real devices

Comment: I just noticed something.
The duplication is only happening if the name (first or last) is less than 8 characters.